# Field 'id' expected a number but got ' '. But I dont even have a field named 'id'

Tags: reactjs, django, postgresql, web-applications, model

we are making a web app using Django, postgresql, and reactjs. I am creating two models and connecting them using one to one relationship in django. The view file is literally empty. This is models.py file I changed the primary key fields for each table to avoid the error but it isnot solving anything.I am new to Django. Please help.

```
from django.db import models
class userInfo(models.Model):
    Username=models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    Password=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.Username

class rentDetails(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(
    userInfo,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    primary_key=True
    )
    floor_no=models.CharField(max_length=20,default=True)
    distance=models.IntegerField(default=True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200,default=True)
    area=models.IntegerField(default=True)
    no_of_rooms=models.IntegerField(default=True)
    price=models.IntegerField(default=True)
    property_choices=[
        ('hostel','Hostel'),
        ('house','House') ,
        ('room','Room'),
        ('flat','flat')     
    ]
    property_type=models.CharField(
    max_length=10,
    choices=property_choices,
    
   )
    images=models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',null=True)
 
#Here's the traceback:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\CHAANO\Chano\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\CHAANO\Chano\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    " ".join(
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\python 310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 296, in _iter_column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\python 310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 410, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\python 310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1126, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\python 310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 910, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\python 310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2668, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\python 310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1990, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ' '.
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback? There will be an id column on the model even if you don't declare one explicitly in your models.py file

Comment: post your traceback, without knowing what the error is, you can't be helped. So please update the question with full traceback

Comment: I just added the traceback .Thankyou so much.